# Unable to execute playground wso2 identity server oauth example

Tags: wso2, identity

Whenever i click on `GetPhotos`, playground (oauth2.jsp) gives me this error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me with IS-4.1.0, Tomcat-7.0.41, and the WAR file downloaded from:
https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/scratch/Identity-Server-4.5.0/M6/samples/playground.war

See:
http://sureshatt.blogspot.com.es/2013/08/openid-connect-with-wso2-identity.html

It seems there are different Playground app versions out there, some are buggy or outdated.

Also you must make sure you enter the exact strings as OAuth2 Playground parameters (id, secret,...). It happened to me that even copy-pasting them within Firefox it didn't work, so make sure you trim those strings yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the webapp you are running does not trust the keys from the identity server.  See steps 9-10 on http://docs.wso2.org/display/IS450/WSO2+Identity+Server+as+an+OpenID+Provider